# Netsuite : First Few Actions that need to be taken for learning

Tags: netsuite

I got Developer Account of Netsuite. And Know Javascript well. Downloaded SuiteCloud in Eclipse (Though my first Suitelet code is showing errors when I ran it on eclipse as shown in the help centre). Can use Help Centre and Also I have register for the Forum.

Now I need to learn Netsuite, so what should be my first few steps that needs to be taken so that I can proceed properly with learning.

Your guidance will be valuable.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards
Glad

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you already owned a Dev account and have eclipse setup with you, so I guess you might have already learnt the essentials of using eclipse plugin for Netsuite. I would rather recommend to play with some client and user event script samples (NS help center) and the deployment process to have an idea how the whole process works in conjunction with record objects. Learning Suitelet involves a lot of learning curves. So better off you jump into Suitelet once you have enough knowledge on the script types and their usages.

Comment: Thanks Rockstar,

You are truly a helping person.